# "RangeError (index)" when trying to replicate the Netflix UI by using Flutter and Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm making clone of Netflix-UI by using flutter and firebase. And I have some problem about it. I've been trying to solve it for 1 week but I can't.

When I run this app it has message

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0'

I upload my project in github.. plz help
https://github.com/woosihyeon/fluuterandfirebase_app

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluuterandfirebase_app/model_movie/model_movie.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:fluuterandfirebase_app/widget/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:fluuterandfirebase_app/widget/circle_slider.dart';
import 'package:fluuterandfirebase_app/widget/box_slider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}


class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamData;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamData = firebaseFirestore.collection('movies').snapshots();
  }

  Widget _fetchData(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildBody(context, snapshot.data.docs);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context,List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
    List<Movie> movies = snapshot.map((d) => Movie.fromSnapshot(d)).toList();
    return ListView(
      children:<Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CarouseImage(movies: movies),
            TopBar(),
          ],
        ),
        CircleSlider(
          movies: movies,
        ),
        BoxSlider(
          movise: movies,
        ),
      ],
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _fetchData(context);
  }
}

class TopBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 7, 20, 7),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            'images/bbongflix_logo.png',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            height: 25.0,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1),
            child: Text(
              'TV 프로그램',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1),
            child: Text(
              '영화',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1),
            child: Text(
              '내가 찜한 콘텐츠',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi There. There error isn't in this file. Check your console and give us the line where you are getting the erorr.

Comment: I upload my github... Can you check it???